# Trying to run Awesomium webcontrol (form element) in different thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, awesomium

I'm utilizing Awesomium to open my scraper pages. I have a form with a webcontrol, which is initalized on creation and source is set. Though, if I were to open multiple, it would give an error saying its different from the calling thread.

Fixed that using a dedicated WebCore thread, and using WebCore.DoWork(() => {});

Although when I open the form in the DoWork function, the UI is unresponsive. What can I do to fix this?

```
            WebCore.DoWork(() =>
        {
                var checkoutForm = new F_Checkout(selectedCSuccess);
                checkoutForm.Show();
            return selectedCSuccess;
        });
```

Sincerely yours.

Comment: All UI elements must be created on the UI thread. You can't create them on multiple threads. The only thing you multi-thread is data processing. You can't even access properties of UI elements safely from non-UI threads.